# using AudioPlayer in flutter gives this error

Tags: flutter, dart

Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method play on channel danielr2001/audioplayer)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:5037:11)
at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:59189/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:943:21)
at _invokeMethod.next ()
at http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:37374:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:37245:59)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:32501:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:33028:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:33066:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:32914:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:32935:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:37497:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:37503:13)
at http://localhost:59189/dart_sdk.js:33274:9

Comment: can somebody tell me how to resolve it my pubspec.yaml file
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  audioplayers: ^0.19.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  flutter_exoplayer: ^0.6.1

Comment: are you trying to run this on destop flutter

Comment: audioplayers only works for Android, iOS, macOS, Web. As Muhammad hinted, you'll usually get this exception when trying to run it on Windows or Linux (no implementation, missing plugin).